# ENOENT (error -4058) during create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, createjs

when i type npm command create-react-app my-app i have error like this :

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\System32;

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\th-wedding\template

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\System32; ENOENT

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-02T04_41_46_601Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried every way, from setting up the env, and reinstalling with a different version, but still the error

Comment: `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: still the same, still the error

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` then `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: I have done that too before, the result is still error

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: it might be windows related issue. do not too much about windows

Comment: same like the first error

Comment: Please show the actual command you're running, and where, in your post. Right now this is a partial log showing a call to `spawn C:\Windows\System32`, which is a nonsense call: you can't run a directory. So: what dir are you in, and what command do you actually issue.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this using the following command.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 2):

ENOENT means `There is no directory exists with this name`

Now You need to check several points:

1. Check the version of node js & npm (check version installed is proper)
2. remove cache (`npm cache clean --force` or `npm cache clean`)
3. verify removed cache (`npm cache verify --force` or `npm cache verify`)
4. check the installed version or install the new version or re-install again  of react react-dom react-scripts using (`npm install --save react create-react-app`)
5. then create a new app using `npx create-react-app app-name`
6. Of If your project is already created then install necessary dependencies using (`npm install`)

Answer (score 1):

It is because npx is not using the latest version to create the project. You can solve this issue by first uninstalling the global npm package using **npm uninstall -g create-react-app** in command prompt and then create project using **npx create-react-app my-app** in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same :)
One question: if I follow your points 5 and 6, I'll "overwrite" all my code, won't I?
Valerie

Comment: J'ai trouvé !!!!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35621974)