# My create react app not working i am trying for two days

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

$  npx create-react-app reactproject
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop
npm ERR! path D:\WebDev\React
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-21T08_08_55_934Z-debug-0.log

i want some one help me please l needed for my project.

Answer (score 1):

most probably this related to npm installation, try to uninstall and reinstall again.

Comment: i try it several time but it was not working . i totally uninstall node js and installed again but its not working

Comment: first of all open the file that you C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-21T08_08_55_934Z-debug-0.log for more details. second thing to do try to install the npm using administrator privilage, see this link:https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/npm-err-code-enoent-syscall-open

Comment: $ npm -v
10.2.1

Comment: better to share the log file

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop
npm ERR! path D:\WebDev\React\04bgChanger
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-22T05_08_05_892Z-debug-0.log

Comment: still same problem

Comment: comment section has limitation so i am unable to share it

Comment: sir please help me

Comment: just open the file C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-22T05_08_05_892Z-debug-0.log and see if the contetnt related the permission, still i guess you should reinstall the npm using administrator privilage

Comment: try npm cache clean, and restart the PC

Comment: but sir to reinstall the npm using administrator privilage

Comment: 30 timing npm:load Completed in 45ms
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 4 files
32 timing command:run Completed in 13ms
33 verbose stack Error: spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop ENOENT
33 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:284:19)
33 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
33 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
34 verbose pkgid 04bgchanger@0.0.0

Comment: 35 verbose cwd D:\WebDev\React\04bgChanger
36 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
37 verbose node v18.18.2
38 verbose npm  v10.2.1
39 error code ENOENT
40 error syscall spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop
41 error path D:\WebDev\React\04bgChanger
42 error errno -4058

Comment: 43 error enoent spawn C:\Users\SUJITKUMAR\Desktop ENOENT
44 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
44 error enoent
45 verbose exit -4058
46 timing npm Completed in 114ms
47 verbose code -4058

Comment: error started from here

Comment: did you try to uninstall then restart, after the restart  make sure that the old files are removed then login as administrator or run the instalation as administrator ?

Comment: sir facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1- First run `npm install -g npm`, then run your `npx create-react-app reactproject` command again.

2- Sometimes, a process running in the background can interfere with the command, try closing as many extra processes you're completely sure you won't need, then try executing your command.

3- Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319194/6851045)

Comment: still getting the same problem