How to fix this in on creating react app npm ERR! enoent spawn pwsh.exe ENOENT
I am trying to create react project then suddenly on creating react app this come and says that pwsh.exe spawn i reinstalled node js and vs code even put the path on the environmental variable but nothing happens
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\My files>npx create-react-app varn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn pwsh.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\My files
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn pwsh.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-01T12_04_59_782Z-debug-0.log
i reinstalled node js and vs code even put the path on the environmental variable but nothing happens

Related, at least: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318869/enoent-error-4058-during-create-react-app

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is because npx is not using the latest version to create the project.
You can check out the solution here.
ENOENT (error -4058) during create-react-app
